# Cleaning a MacBook Pro keyboard that's been covered in juice

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

My lovely son spilled apple juice on my laptop keyboard.

It works, but it feels like it has grit under the keys and sticks a bit.

How do I clean it out?

I remember old keyboards could be just banged hard against the desk... I presume thats a bad idea though...

It's a macbook pro 15 inch laptop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually remove the keys, clean them and then replace them again.

Follow this link to see how it's done: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSpPlMdGvVI

The problem with liquid damage is that although the laptop may work fine now, if the juice has got onto the Logic Board, it can cause corrosion over time, which will more than likely cause issues.

However, I do hope this is not the case! Good luck!

Comment: True indeed. I spilled wine on my old MacBook Pro and quickly cleaned it up. It seemed to be fine so I thought nothing more of it. Months down the road it started having issues, and corrosion from the spilled liquid was deemed to be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Clean all the parts, especially the logicboard. Heat it up and apply flux! Or have a professional do it for you, shouldn’t cost too much. There’s also other cleaning solutions. Most important part, give it a few days to completely dry out afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

Before doing anything I would drop the computer in a big sack of rice to make sure it dries up internally. You don't want any of that juice seeping down the cracks to the motherboard believe me!

Good luck!
TOM

Comment: Sounds like really bad advice to me. Juice + Rice dust = even harder mess to clean up under the keys. And rice in MacBook Pro ports - is this a serious attempt to help someone or more a "how to make a bad situation worse" attempt at humor?

Comment: The rice trick come highly recommended from people with wet iPhones. Google it. Rice, especially when it comes sealed in vacuum bags is super dry. Once exposed to something wetter, like apple juice stuck within a computer, that humidity will transfer to the rice.